# CLI describe error: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Tags: sql, oracle

```sql
select PR.Create_date,
       PR.CUST_APP_NO,
       PR.Cont_plan_ID,
       PL.product_name,
       mem.proposal_info_fk,
       mem.o_id,
       qa.qus_id_fk,
       qa.qus_response
from   ADMIN.t_proposal_info PR
       INNER JOIN admin.T_plan_type PL
       on replace(PR.CONT_PLAN_ID,'~',NULL)=pl.plan_code
       inner join ADMIN.t_member_info mem
       on pr.o_id=mem.proposal_info_fk
       INNER JOIN ADMIN.t_short_qus_ans QA
       on mem.proposal_info_fk=qa.proposer_id_fk`your text`
       inner join ADMIN.t_short_qus_ans QA
       on mem.o_id=qa.member_id_fk
where  pl.plan_product_type_fk='105'
and    qa.qus_id_fk in ('5','91')
and    qa.qus_response='No'
and    pr.is_cust_split='No'
and    pr.cust_renew_flag='~N'
and    pr.create_date>='01-MAY-23';`
```

Comment: You make `join` to the same table twice (ADMIN.t_short_qus_ans). Either remove one of them or change the second one's alias (meaning, make it something different than QA). If you chose to do the latter, do not forget to use the new alias on your selected field(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you used the same alias in two joins.
So, what is wrong is:

```
 INNER JOIN ADMIN.t_short_qus_ans QA on mem.proposal_info_fk=qa.proposer_id_fkyour text 
 inner join ADMIN.t_short_qus_ans QA on mem.o_id=qa.member_id_fk
```

Instead, it should be something like below:

```
 INNER JOIN ADMIN.t_short_qus_ans QA on mem.proposal_info_fk=qa.proposer_id_fkyour text 
 inner join ADMIN.t_short_qus_ans QA2 on mem.o_id=qa2.member_id_fk
```

So far, I haven't seen any other thing that appear to me like not being OK.
My advice: whenever you have a complex query, start small, writing one filter condition and one join at a time and testing how it runs in sqldeveloper or some other IDE for Oracle or, eventually some othe more fancy IDE, which works on several brands of databases (like DBeaver or DBArtisan). So you may know sooner when you make a mistake and fix the errors easier.